# how to make a responsive navigation on the top

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive navigation on my website.
i didn't use a grid
I tried

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.menu{
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    float: top;
```

}}

but that don't work
I want it to get on the top of my website

Comment: `float:top` does not exist

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: code formatting is also not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are many references available on the web you can take references from w3schools.com, bootstrap, codepen etc.

try below one,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

References:

1. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/
2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Note: `float:top` is not working

Comment: `float:top` does not exist, only `float:left` and `float:right` exist, and your answer's `link` is not the link, it is text, see how to write answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Now links are not text.

Answer (score 0):

So some suggestions:
Send the html code or jsut some of it.
You can also try adding margin: 0; to the body:

```
body{
 margin: 0;
}
```

You will also need to add a background - color:

```
.menu {
 background-color: red;
}
```

And more stuff could be added but you can check this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_header.asp
This helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this codepen which I had made yesterday or may be before that, I don't remember :-

https://codepen.io/CodingPencil/pen/abEWzXp

Or just copy my code here :-

HTML -

```
 <nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Something</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS -

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --nav-bg: #03000e;
  --main-clr: dodgerblue;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #03000e;
}

nav .logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration-color: var(--main-clr);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

nav ul {
  --padding: 20px;
  --font-size: 17px;

  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: var(--padding);
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2.5px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background: var(--main-clr);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav .menu {
  width: 22px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

nav .menu span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: left;
}

nav .menu.active span {
  background: var(--main-clr);
}

nav .menu.active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

nav .menu span:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: left;
}

nav .menu.active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

nav .menu.active span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(0);
}

@media (max-width: 910px) {
  nav .menu {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav ul {
    --height: 0px;

    flex-direction: column;
    background: var(--nav-bg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 56px;
    height: var(--height);
    transition: 1s ease;
  }

  nav ul.active {
    --height: calc(
      (((var(--padding) * 2) + (var(--font-size) * 1.5))) * var(--childenNumber)
    );
    transition: 1s ease;
  }

  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}
```

And the JAVASCRIPT -

```
const navigation = document.getElementById("nav");
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigation.style.setProperty("--childenNumber", navigation.children.length);

  navigation.classList.toggle("active");
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
});
```